# How do I compress HTML in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, html-compression

In Laravel 4.0, I use the code below to compress the HTML laravel response outputs to browser, however it doesn't work in laravel 5.

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    if($response instanceof Illuminate\Http\Response)
    {
        $buffer = $response->getContent();
        if(strpos($buffer,'<pre>') !== false)
        {
            $replace = array(
                '/<!--[^\[](.*?)[^\]]-->/s' => '',
                "/<\?php/"                  => '<?php ',
                "/\r/"                      => '',
                "/>\n</"                    => '><',
                "/>\s+\n</"                 => '><',
                "/>\n\s+</"                 => '><',
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $replace = array(
                '/<!--[^\[](.*?)[^\]]-->/s' => '',
                "/<\?php/"                  => '<?php ',
                "/\n([\S])/"                => '$1',
                "/\r/"                      => '',
                "/\n/"                      => '',
                "/\t/"                      => '',
                "/ +/"                      => ' ',
            );
        }
        $buffer = preg_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $buffer);
        $response->setContent($buffer);
    }
});
```

Please how do i make this work in Laravel 5.

OR

Please provide a better way of compressing HTML in laravel 5 if any.
Thanks in advance.

NB: I don't wish to use any laravel package for compressing html, just need a simple code that does the work without killing performance.

Comment: I know you said you dont want a pacakge - but https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-HTMLMin is the perfect solution. And it wont 'kill performance' any differently than if you did it yourself.

Comment: I would advise against what you are trying to do _at all_ – a `pre` element is not the only thing where white space might matter, but also inside a `textarea`/`input` or basically in _any_ element if it gets later on _formatted_ via CSS (`white-space`). Just __GZip__ the output before sending it to the client, that is much more effective than messing with the HTML code itself.

Comment: @cbroe how do I use GZip? any working example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended way to do this in Larvel 5 is to rewrite your function as [middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware). As stated in the docs:

..this middleware would perform its task **after** the request is handled by the application:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class AfterMiddleware implements Middleware {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        // Perform action

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. How do I use it? Am running this on each request?

Comment: Yes you'd run it on every http request. You can register it globally by adding your class in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Answer (score 25):

Complete code is this (with custom GZip enabled) :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class OptimizeMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $buffer = $response->getContent();
        if(strpos($buffer,'<pre>') !== false)
        {
            $replace = array(
                '/<!--[^\[](.*?)[^\]]-->/s' => '',
                "/<\?php/"                  => '<?php ',
                "/\r/"                      => '',
                "/>\n</"                    => '><',
                "/>\s+\n</"                 => '><',
                "/>\n\s+</"                 => '><',
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $replace = array(
                '/<!--[^\[](.*?)[^\]]-->/s' => '',
                "/<\?php/"                  => '<?php ',
                "/\n([\S])/"                => '$1',
                "/\r/"                      => '',
                "/\n/"                      => '',
                "/\t/"                      => '',
                "/ +/"                      => ' ',
            );
        }
        $buffer = preg_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $buffer);
        $response->setContent($buffer);
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'On'); // If you like to enable GZip, too!
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Please check your browser network inspector for `Content-Length` header before/after implement this code.

enjoy it ... :).. .

Comment: (index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery not working after that

Comment: @Rahul Tathod This middleware will only compress HTML, and enable GZip. These two compresses doesn't effect on Jquery, or CSS, JS files. If there is any problem, you should find root cause.

Answer (score 22):

It is not very good solution to minify html in middleware as you can spend a lot of CPU time on it and it runs on every request.

Instead it is better to use htmlmin package ( https://github.com/HTMLMin/Laravel-HTMLMin ):

```
composer require htmlmin/htmlmin
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Minifying HTML on blade template level and caching it in storage should be much more effective.

Comment: will this still work if there are variables in your template that need to be accounted for on every request? Or even whole blocks that depend on conditions?

Comment: 2021 update: this package seems to have a lot of bugs and doesn't seem to be maintained.

Comment: does not work, lack of documentation for usage
one of the worst packages i ever installed and uninstalled after 10mins

Answer (score 4):

I have created a webpack plugin to solve same purpose.[MinifyHtmlWebpackPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify-html-webpack-plugin)

Install the plugin with npm:

```sh
$ npm install minify-html-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

## For Laravel Mix Users

Paste below snippets into mix.js file.

```js
    const MinifyHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('minify-html-webpack-plugin');
    const mix = require('laravel-mix');

    mix.webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new MinifyHtmlWebpackPlugin({
                src: './storage/framework/views',
                ignoreFileNameRegex: /\.(gitignore)$/,
                rules: {
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeComments: true,
                    minifyJS: true,
                }
            })
        ]
    });
```

It will minify all view files during the Webpack build.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost a copy of [Vahid's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37510913/2836233) answer but it fixes two problems.

1) It checks if a response is a `BinaryFileResponse` as any attempt to modify this type of response will throw an Exception.

2) It retained newline characters as the complete elimination of newlines will lead to bad Javascript code on lines with single-line comment.

For example, the code below

```
 var a; //This is a variable
 var b; //This will be commented out
```

Will become

```
 var a; //This is a variable var b; //This will be commented out
```

Note: At the time of this answer I couldn't get my hands on a good regex to match single line comments without complications or rather, ignore newlines on only lines with a single-line comment, so I'm hoping for a better fix.

Here's the modified version.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class OptimizeMiddleware {

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    if ($response instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse) {
        return $response;
    } else {
        $buffer = $response->getContent();
        if (strpos($buffer, '<pre>') !== false) {
            $replace = array(
                '/<!--[^\[](.*?)[^\]]-->/s' => '',
                "/<\?php/" => '<?php ',
                "/\r/" => '',
                "/>\n</" => '><',
                "/>\s+\n</" => '><',
                "/>\n\s+</" => '><',
            );
        } else {
            $replace = array(
                '/<!--[^\[](.*?)[^\]]-->/s' => '',
                "/<\?php/" => '<?php ',
                "/\n([\S])/" => '$1',
                "/\r/" => '',
                "/\n+/" => "\n",
                "/\t/" => '',
                "/ +/" => ' ',
            );
        }
        $buffer = preg_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $buffer);
        $response->setContent($buffer);
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'On'); //enable GZip, too!
        return $response;
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Compressing output for every request using the middleware truly is really a bad idea, I recommend you check out [this solution by Jokerius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45733044/2836233)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you are rendering the view manually:

```php
echo view('example.site')->render(function($view, $content) { 
    return preg_replace(
            ['/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s'],
            ['>', '<', '\\1'],
            $content
    ); }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This package is much better option in my opinion [renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed](https://github.com/renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed)

Answer (score 0):

I did it with very simple code.
**Example: welcome.blade.php**

Add the following code to the beginning of the page

```
<?php ob_start('compress_page');?>
```

Add the following code to the end of the page：

```
<?php   
ob_end_flush();
function compress_page($buffer) {
    $search = array("/>[[:space:]]+/", "/[[:space:]]+</");
    $replace = array(">","<");
    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
}?>
```

**Full page code example:**

```html
<?php ob_start('compress_page');?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #636b6f;
                font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 100;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            }
            .full-height {
                height: 100vh;
            }
            .flex-center {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }
            .position-ref {
                position: relative;
            }
            .top-right {
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                top: 18px;
            }
            .content {
                text-align: center;
            }
            .title {
                font-size: 84px;
            }
            .links > a {
                color: #636b6f;
                padding: 0 25px;
                font-size: 12px;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: .1rem;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            .m-b-md {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
                        <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Laravel
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Documentation</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php   
    ob_end_flush();
    function compress_page($buffer) {
        $search = array("/>[[:space:]]+/", "/[[:space:]]+</");
        $replace = array(">","<");
        return preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
    }?>
```

Answer (score -1):

this is best way.. we don't need to use laravel packeges .Thanks..

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class OptimizeMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $buffer = $response->getContent();
        if(strpos($buffer,'<pre>') !== false)
        {
            $replace = array(
                '/<!--[^\[](.*?)[^\]]-->/s' => '',
                "/<\?php/"                  => '<?php ',
                "/\r/"                      => '',
                "/>\n</"                    => '><',
                "/>\s+\n</"                 => '><',
                "/>\n\s+</"                 => '><',
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $replace = array(
                '/<!--[^\[](.*?)[^\]]-->/s' => '',
                "/<\?php/"                  => '<?php ',
                "/\n([\S])/"                => '$1',
                "/\r/"                      => '',
                "/\n/"                      => '',
                "/\t/"                      => '',
                "/ +/"                      => ' ',
            );
        }
        $buffer = preg_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $buffer);
        $response->setContent($buffer);
        ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'On'); // If you like to enable GZip, too!
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code snippet doesn't seem to run.

Answer (score -3):

For easy compression, I build my own laravel module. This module will compress all the final html output before sending to the client (browser).

You can also target multiple environment at a time using `.env` file.

More details on how to install and configure will be [found here](https://github.com/vrkansagara/LaraOutPress/blob/master/README.md)